# Apply aggregation dynamically to Linq IGrouping element

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do some basic aggregation on a `Collection<Dictionary<string,object>>` . The fields to group and aggregate change every time, and so do the aggregation functions to apply. I am able to group the elements, now I want to know how to apply a custom aggregate function selected by the user.

Example:

```
// Data I want to aggregate
Collection<Dictionary<string,object>> userData;
// The key is the field, and the value is the name of the aggregate function to apply. Ex: {"distance", "average"},{"time","sum"},{"price","customAgg"}
Dictionary<string,string> fieldsToAggregate; 

var groupedData = userData.GroupBy( /* here I selected all the fields that are not being aggregated */ )

foreach(var group in groupedData)
{
  // Here is where I don't know how to best handle it ...
}
```

My current approach is to do a `switch()` on the `fieldsToAggregate` and call the function it refers to (either be existing Linq aggregation like .Sum() or custom defined somewhere else in the code).

```
case "sum":
   group.Sum(/* I select here the appropriate field */);
   break;
```

This too static, and other applications/classes won't be able to extend this functionality. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe with `.Aggregate()` with a Delegate ?

Comment: Yes, You can use Aggregate with delegate, have you tried that?

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan I started that route, looks promising. I just wanted to see if there is a more flexible and maintainable way of doing it

Comment: It depends where do you have this string literals stored, and if you can keep actions directly... if you can, than I would go with delegates if I would you

Comment: Does Dynamic Linq helps? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a pivot table. Have you looked at any of the hundreds of implementations of pivot tables in .net?

Comment: If the data was place int a datatable it is easy to select the filed of the dictionary which is a string : Collection<Dictionary<string,object>> userData = dt.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("columnName"), y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault));

Comment: @Eric , care to explain how you think it might help? Extending  Dynamic Linq to allow custom aggregation functions looks like a pain, and does not really answer my question which is about deciding which aggregations to do.

Comment: @Aron Making a pivot table out of this still leaves the question unanswered. I don't care about how the data is represented. I just need a flexible way of deciding at runtime which aggregation I'll apply. If the class that holds this piece is called externally, it should let you pass your own set of aggregation functions, so you can extend the functionality to your liking

Comment: @GalmWing No. A pivot table actually solves your ENTIRE problem, not just the one you are asking. A pivot table is a pattern that allows you to dynamically sort and group items and then apply aggregations to each item, ALL DYNAMICALLY. As for "extend this functionality" what were you expecting to have, the user write their own map/reduce function?